# Check if a Document Uri is of External SD Card Root

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

How can we check whether the selected document using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is the external SD Card root or not?

Comment: Why do you care? If the user wants to use some other document tree, let them. After all, it is the user's device, not yours.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am performing some operations which needs SD Card access. I need to show an alert to the user when they didn't select external SD Card.

Comment: @noob Did you find any solution?

Comment: @WonderSoftwares Please check my answer.

Comment: Very nice @noob.. It works really well. Helped me a lot. Already given +1 to your answer. Thank you

Comment: @WonderSoftwares Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here're the functions I am using for determining if the Uri is of External SD Card and whether it's situated at the root of the SD card or not

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static boolean checkIfSDCardRoot(Uri uri) {
    return isExternalStorageDocument(uri) && isRootUri(uri) && !isInternalStorage(uri);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static boolean isRootUri(Uri uri) {
    String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri);
    return docId.endsWith(":");
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static boolean isInternalStorage(Uri uri) {
    return isExternalStorageDocument(uri) && DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri).contains("primary");
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

These methods are taken from the library I have created for dealing with the Storage Access Framework. The library is open-sourced and present on Github - [NoobFileChooser](https://github.com/Abhi347/NoobFileChooser). The functions are present in [this file](https://github.com/Abhi347/NoobFileChooser/blob/master/noobfilechooser/src/main/java/com/noob/noobfilechooser/managers/NoobSAFManager.java).